# Find unused Javascript functions?

Tags: javascript

I have around 100 .js files in my application.  I need to find the unused functions from these files.

Which editor or tool can help me?

Comment: I dont' this there is a way to do it completely. Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167663/is-there-a-tool-to-remove-unused-methods-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a tool to remove unused methods in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167663/is-there-a-tool-to-remove-unused-methods-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9):

Give a look to the [JSLint](http://jslint.com/help.html) code quality tool.

Comment: How does JSLint need to be configured to show warnings about unused functions?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [Jsure](https://github.com/berke/jsure), a Javascript lint implementation. You'll be looking for the `-unused-funs` flag

Answer (score 1):

Necromancing for the sake of completeness:

*On the frontend* you can now use modern browsers' devtools, which now have the "Coverage" tab (at least Chromium-based do).

This tab allows you to "record" user activity for some time and then inspect which parts of JS files haven't been called/executed. Works for CSS too.

In dev tools press `Ctrl + Shif + P` to bring up the command bar, start typing "Cover.." and the "enable Coverage tab" will pop up. Then press "record" at the bottom area.