# Find unused CSS rule and js script in a web project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

HI..
My project has many CSS roles and JavaScript scripts that are not used in my project. How can I find these unused files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find unused images and CSS styles in a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242/how-can-i-find-unused-images-and-css-styles-in-a-website)

Answer (score 10):

There is a nice little firefox plugin called [Dust Me Selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/), which scans a page for CSS which isn't being used.

It's a very good tool for spotting things in your stylesheets which are redundant.

However, you still need to be careful with it, as it is quite possible for a stylesheet to be unused when you run the program, but still necessary for your site - ie it could be used for dynamic content, or for other pages which share the same stylesheet code, etc.

[EDIT]

I've removed my previous edit where I noted that this project might have been abandoned, because in fact it looks like it's back in active development. Good news all round.

Comment: +1 Chrome's developer tools can also do this, just run a performance check in the 'Audit' tab.

Comment: +1 from me as well, I love the idea of a CSS code coverage tool.

Answer (score 8):

When I've needed to do this, I've used the search feature of the dev environment to search all files in the solution for the filename of the file I suspected wasn't used. If it didn't get found, or got found only within the file itself, I knew it wasn't used, since the files have to be referenced (via a `script` or `link` element, or in a script that combines and minifies them) to be used.

Of course, if you're building filenames up from component parts, that won't work. For instance, if you have code with a variable `basename` containing "foo" and then code outputting a script tag like:

```
<script src="<%=basename%>-bar.js"></script>
```

...then my search for "foo-bar.js" won't find it. If that's a real possibility in your code, you'll have to find all the `script` and `link` elements and check them yourself...

...or experiment: Deploy your solution, and on the server, delete each file you think might not be used, refresh on the browser, and look for 404s in the console.

---

...all of which relates to unused *files*. If you think the files are *referenced*, but their contents aren't used, you'll either need to selectively remove the references and see what breaks (blech, a manual and error-prone process) or you'll need a code coverage analysis tool. [This question here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249/are-there-any-good-javascript-code-coverage-tools) discusses code coverage analysis tools for JavaScript, and [Spudley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211967/find-unused-css-role-and-js-script-in-a-web-project/6212006#6212006) here points to a "code coverage" (for lack of a better term) tool for CSS.