# Find out what CSS styles are being used on a given page

Tags: css, http, styles

I have a page that contains multiple stylesheets and a large majority of the styles in it aren't actually used in the page (deprecated etc). I would like to **export a new stylesheet** containing all styles on the page that are actually in use. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check which CSS styles are being used or not used on a web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361007/is-there-a-way-to-check-which-css-styles-are-being-used-or-not-used-on-a-web-pag)

Comment: I found that dupe by Googling your question word for word.

Comment: this could be of help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224154/find-unused-images-css-rules-js-script-blocks

Comment: None of these are a valid solution they all focus on showing unused not **exporting used**. I have done my research.

Comment: Actually, i am not sure this would be a good idea, something like : javascript trigered selectors, contextual display, code conditional layout ...

Comment: @MilchePatern good point, still interested in trying it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this website does what you want: [CSS Trashman](http://www.csstrashman.com/). It takes a little while to run, but it works. It reduced my personal site's CSS from 3.31 KB to 402 Bytes.

If you would rather use a command-line tool, [CSS Rationator](https://github.com/begriffs/css-ratiocinator) powers CSS Trashman.

Comment: http://www.csstrashman.com/ only redirects to https://github.com/begriffs/css-ratiocinator Date: 2015-04-02

Comment: I was looking for the same thing and i came up with a small javascript to do this. You can check it out at https://github.com/mocanuga/unusedCSS

Comment: @mocanuga How are we supposed to use that?

Comment: Just create a bookmark and paste the code in the href field. Then you go to the website you want to get the css, and click the bookmark you created.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue, complicated by the fact that the pages I need to analyze are login-only, and for work, so I cannot provide my login to an external app (which is how unused-css.com crawls pages behind a login wall).

I found two Chrome extensions:

1. [CSS Remove and Combine](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-remove-and-combine/cdfmaaeapjmacolkojefhfollmphonoh?hl=en-GB)
2. [unusedCSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unusedcss/dokggbghedajooenkgjbamikfgnngeik?hl=en-US)

I only used the first, as it did the trick nicely. It counted CSS elements on the page, told me how many were used and unused, and let me download a stylesheet of all used elements. It did not seem to include functionality for browsing around a site and accumulating seen elements, it was just on a page-by-page basis, but it still let me prune 450 down to 150.

Comment: https://extpose.com/ext/10145 - delisted ?? ; https://github.com/genintho/unusedCSS ; http://web.archive.org/web/20170222113001/https://www.bleachcss.com/

Answer (score 2):

In the [**Chrome DevTools**](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), there is an Audits tab that will allow you to run a Web Page Performance audit and see a list of unused CSS rules :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found this : http://unused-css.com/

> Features
>
> - Explore the pages of your site automatically, find the unused CSS selectors and create new clean CSS files you can download
> - Authenticate and explore the pages requiring authentication. It will then check unused CSS rules.
> - Search for CSS rules in javascript files
> - Customize the list of CSS selectors to keep
> - Preview the change made to the CSS file
> - Follow CSS import commands
> - Set a user agent for the crawler

But i am not sure this would be a good idea, something like : javascript trigered selectors, contextual display, code conditional layout ... So, be carefull if you attempt to 'batch' work your .css files.

Comment: Seems impossible to get the results without paying.