# Which js file is running on which element of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, browser-plugin

I have downloaded a responsive bootstrap website template. It has a lot more extra content and js files that i don't need for my website. I want to remove it along with .js file being used for that content. Is there any plugin or way to find out which js file is being used on which content so that i could make changes accordingly ??
Thanks,
Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this question. 
I believe you should be able to find out something that should help you in the answer to that question

[find unused images, css rules, js script blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224154/find-unused-images-css-rules-js-script-blocks)