# How To See If I'm Using JS Dependencies on my WebSite

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

To build a website I got a predesigned template from *WrapBootstrap*. After I added it to my project, I deleted some HTML unused parts. For visual effect (e.g. fade effect and others) the template uses a lot of Javascript files as dependencies. I'm sure some of them are actually unused.

There's a automated way to check if I'm still using some of them? I will keep them and remove the unused.

This for *performance purposes*.

Comment: Search SO for "unused js" or "dead code". Some good examples are at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224154/find-unused-images-css-rules-js-script-blocks and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169889/find-unused-javascript-functions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174988/detect-linked-unused-files-and-unused-javascript