# Find function invocations across node files

Tags: node.js, function

Is there a way to find all the places across a project where a particular function is invoked? In particular, taking into account any times that the file is imported.

For example, if we're looking for where `library.js`'s `function foobar()` is used, this example in another file would be included:

```
var library = require('./myfile.js')
library.foobar()
```

(The reason simply searching for `foobar` across all files won't work is if the function is a common name used in multiple  modules.)

This would be the opposite of something like Webstorm's [Jump to Definition](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/) feature.

One of the use-cases is to help refactor a legacy codebase where it's unclear where certain exported functions are being used, or if they're being used at all.

I saw similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169889/find-unused-javascript-functions), but these seem to be for client-side javascript and don't take exports into account.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime I use [`callsite`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/callsite) module in the function I want to check for log the absolute link to file use this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 
`console.trace();` inside your function and you will know where does it called.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this doesn't exactly work in this case because the function might not be called at all. I'm looking for a static analyzer, instead of needing to execute over the whole codebase at runtime.