# Find all unused Javascript and CSS files in my application

Tags: javascript, java, performance, analytics

Is there a way to find unused javascript files ? As I am working on very big and old application and many people have worked on this application and recently we have made it responsive and added bootstrap as well, all others have added Javascript and css files as per their convenience. But now I want to minimize these files and keep only required files in my system.

Kindly suggest any tool to find unused files.

Comment: Is it a web app? A node app? Do you use modules or is it just HTML pages with includes?

Comment: you can write your own tool. get the name and search it inside the code files. if it exists and **not commented**, assume it being used.

Comment: Some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169889/find-unused-javascript-functions

Answer (score 0):

Developer tools in your browser. For example Chrome: Developer tools -> Network

Comment: No. Not in that way.