# finding unused javascript in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a rails project that has too many javascript files. Processing this script takes too much time. I want to remove the unnecessary javascript includes from my application. I am familiar with the plugins that can find unnecessary css but I haven't come across any method of finding unused javascript. If anyone has any idea regarding this please share.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to rjs (Rails-generated) or standard js files? If it's the latter then you can use [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html). For the first type you should have some integration tests that fail when you remove the RJS that is being used, if not you'll have to add those tests first.

For more see: [Is there a tool to remove unused methods in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167663/is-there-a-tool-to-remove-unused-methods-in-javascript)

Comment: I have tried jslint but it does not tell me the files that are unused rather it displays the errors associated with the js code