# Javascript : How to check external javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i check if an external javascript file is being used in the page or not?
I need to cleanup the codes where there many external javascript files imported. I am not the original developer of the code, is there any way to do this?

Any tools or IDE will be better and helps.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a tool to remove unused methods in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167663/is-there-a-tool-to-remove-unused-methods-in-javascript)

Comment: @Purmou, I don't think with have same problem with the post you mentioned.

Comment: @Ken, thank you for the advise, I do read that post before, but I am not sure I understand what you mean? Did I do something wrong here? Please guide me, I may have doing something that I am not aware that is wrong here. Thank you. ^_^

Comment: @Ken, thank you for your guide. I am sorry if I forgot to marked as answers for the response. I will go do that. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Firefox with the Web Developer add-on.

Tools -> Web Developer -> Information -> View JavaScript, then choose "Collapse All" to see a summary

I think Firebug has an option to show includes, too.